# How to use a link_to helper passing an id of associated object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to go to show.html.erb which is a view file just to show the specific comment, and the comment is associated under an article.

How to use `<%= link_to 'Show Comment ? %>`

This is show action in comments controller which may have route like:

```
/articles/3/comments/2
```

2 and 3 as id

```
# commentcontroller
def show
  @article =Article.find(params[:id])
end
```

Comment: Please add some more information to your question to help people understand the code surrounding, ways to replicate the issue and what you've tried to do to resolve it. Also format  your code in the question using the appropriate markup.

Comment: Can you run `rake routes` at the root of the project and show us?

Comment: Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                                       Controller#Action article_comments GET  /articles/:article_id /comments  comments#index
  POST   /articles/:article_id/comments     comments#create
 new_article_comment GET   /articles/:article_id/comments/new      comments#new  article_comment GET    /articles/:article_id/comments/:id    comments#show   PATCH  /articles/:article_id/comments/:id(.:format)      comments#update  PUT    /articles/:article_id/comments/:id(.:format)      comments#update  DELETE /articles/:article_id/comments/:id(.:format)

Comment: @AndréGuimarãesSakata  i just want to use link_to tag and access url of comments view let say  it is index to show all the comments under one article(post) and what would be the routes.rb

Answer (score 0):

Based in your `routes` you putted in the comments, it should work:

`link_to('Show Comment', controller: 'comments', action: 'show', id: comment.id, article_id: comment.article.id)`